# Setting up JSP Server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, installation

OK so at work I've been working with Java to start migrating our legacy database and in-house systems to something more modern. Well today I was asked if there was a way to use HTML/CSS as a front end to the java programs I've made. So my coworker and I have set up Tomcat on our Ubuntu 12.04 server in hopes of using jsp. Now we don't know where to go. I've been using Netbeans for my java development and all the tutorials and articles I've found has been about installing the server on my PC and I think that can't be right. Are there any good, semi-current (as in not from 2003) tutorials or articles for setting this up? Both my coworker and I have experience with PHP and it's not this difficult to set up.

Comment: First link for Tomcat and Ubuntu gave me [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where you install Tomcat, your computer or a separate server. Create your web application, drop the `war` into `tomcat/webapps` and you're ready to go (to http://yourservername.com:8080/nameofwar/). Of course if you've never actually created a web application, there's some additional complications.

If you're familiar with Netbeans, you probably want to create a `Dynamic Web Project`. Plenty of resources to be found with all this info I've given you.